# Switch between WebView activity retain state (without reloading)

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

i want to switch between activities that use WebView layout. 
Here is the scenario

First, i call a WebView activity (say, SecondActivity) from first activity, with an intent containing URL string. Using that string, the so-called activity load the webpage until done.
I then switch back to the first activity by calling startActivity(firstActivity) inside the

Afterwards, when i try to switch back to the SecondActivity, the webpage is reloaded. It seems that the state of the SecondActivity is not saved and method loadUrl(url) is called again.

Answer (score 0):

To switch back to the first activity you could just call `finish()` in the second activity?

Answer (score 0):

The state of an activity when switching from one to another is not possible to maintain. This is because of how the Activity lifecycle works, when an Activity is returned to from another, the onCreate is called again reloading all your views, or whatever code you have in your onCreate, which is probably configuring all your views.

Comment: then what should i do to fix this problem?